# Can not download code from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to download the code from google app engine.
And I installed python, google engine sdk and executed this command

appcfg.py download_app -a ...

and I typed my mail address and password...

but it says

Error 403: ---
You do not have permission to download this app version

What do you think is the problem? Please help me with this.
I am stuck with this like all day but can't find the solution.

Comment: Check that you typed your email and password correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem (Mac OS, running AppEngineLauncher).
Noticed that no apps were running in GAEL.

Running one of the apps in GAEL (earlier version of the same one - could be a coincidence) seemed to make a difference - it started the download, but then halted.

Then I ran appcfg list_versions on that app, followed by download_app.
That seemed to do the job - download continuing as I write this.

On a guess, appcfg got hazy about its security context.  YMMV.

Comment: A day or two later, I saw a news item about GMail login problems.  My security context for this is tied to Gmail login, so I'd be more inclined to suspect that was the problem.  (Code downloaded started and then stopped partway through, which smells more like an intermittent issue...)

Answer (score 0):

Check:

Only the developer who uploaded the code and the application owner(s) can download it. If anyone other than these parties attempts to download the app, they'll see an error message like the following: Error 403

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code

or your app have set permanently prohibit code downloads. Check on page: https://appengine.google.com/deployment/codelock?app_id=your_app_id&to_forward=/permissions?app_id=your_app_id

Answer (score 0):

Adding flag `--no_cookies` worked for me.